# What does ... mean in {a, b, ...others} = myObject?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

What does the `...` in `{onClick, onMouseover, ...others}` syntax mean in the following ES6/Typescript/React snippet? It did not follow the `others` variable later in code.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    {onClick, onMouseover, ...others} = this.props.listeners;

    _.each(others, function(listener) {
        PageStore.removeChangeListener(listener);
    });
}
```

Comment: It's a JavaScript (ES6) feature called destructuring assignment - see the linked question above.

Comment: the linked question doesn't explain about the "...", which did not follow the `others` variable later in code

Comment: @joews thanks a lot for editing the question for better clarity :)

Comment: the `...` in `{ a, b , ...others } = obj` means "gather the members from `obj` that have not been assigned into a new object called `others`."

e.g. for `{ a, b, ...others } = { a: 1, b: 2, c:3 , d: 4 }`, `others` would be `{ c: 3 , d: 4 }`.

Comment: `...` is either the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator, or in this case the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) operator

Comment: @azium: Almost but not quite. Object rest [is an ES7 proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread).

Comment: The linked duplicate question clearly does not provide any relevant to explanation of `...`. How to reopen this question?